# Android manifest updated incorrectly with Google Play Services dependency

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to implement a Maps feature for a Xamarin.Forms app.
However, my Android manifest file is causing issues due to auto-generated elements at build time.

My original android manifest file looks like the following:

```
<!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my_api_key" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

When I rebuild my solution, the following gets generated:

```
<!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOURmy_api_key_API_KEY" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/2" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Notice how my api key is now modified unexpectedly and duplicate version elements get generated.

One of the generated elements causes a build error:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/2" />
```

In conclusion, I'm blocked from making any progress.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi had to physically delete all the files from the following directories:**

.Droid\obj\Debug

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Xamarin

**I then made sure I had the following:**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```